# C++ object [implementation] operator== error

Tags: c++

I have made an `object` class in C++, which works fine, apart from 1/2 parts - the boolean `==` and `!=` operators. I tried, as below, with 2 objects, both initalized as `5`. However, when using the `==` operator, it returns `false` (and `true` with `!=`), despite when I set a breakpoint on the line which test the `==` operator, they both contained `0x00000005` (`5`). I am not sure what is wrong with my code:

```
class object
{
private:
    class dummy
    {
    public:
        dummy(){}
        virtual ~dummy(){}
        virtual dummy *duplicate() const = 0;
        virtual const std::type_info &type() const = 0;
        void *address;
    };
    template < typename _Ty > class data : public dummy
    {
        friend class object;
    public:
        data(const _Ty &_Value) : __inner(_Value){}
        ~data(){}
        const std::type_info &type() const
        {
            return typeid(_Ty);
        }
        data *duplicate() const
        {
            return new data<_Ty>(__inner);
        }
    private:
        _Ty __inner;
    };
    dummy *d;
public:
    object()
    {
        d->address = NULL;
    }
    template < typename _Ty > object(const _Ty &_Value) : d(new data<_Ty>(_Value))
    {
        d->address = reinterpret_cast<void *>(_Value);
    }
    object(object &_Rhs) : d(_Rhs.d->duplicate()){}
    ~object()
    { 
        if (has_value())
        {
            d->~dummy();
        }
    }
    const std::type_info &type() const
    {
        return d->type();
    }
    template < typename _Ty > _Ty cast() const
    {
        if (typeid(_Ty) != type())
        {
            throw std::exception("");
        }
        return reinterpret_cast< data<_Ty> *>(d)->__inner;
    }
    const object &operator=(object &_Rhs)
    {
        d = _Rhs.d->duplicate();
        return *this;
    }
    template < typename _Ty > const object &operator=(const _Ty &_Value) const
    {
        d = new data<_Ty>(_Value);
        d->address = reinterpret_cast<void *>(_Value);
        return *this;
    }
    template < typename _Ty > bool operator==(const _Ty &_Value) const
    {
        return (type() != typeid(_Ty) ? false : cast<_Ty>() == _Value);
    }
    bool operator==(object &_Rhs) const
    {
        return (type() != typeid(_Rhs.type()) ? false : d->address == _Rhs.d->address); 
                    // Breakpoint tested above ^^^
    }
    template < typename _Ty > bool operator!=(const _Ty &_Value) const
    {
        return (type() == typeid(_Ty) ? false : cast<_Ty>() != _Value);
    }
    bool operator!=(object &_Rhs) const
    {
        return !(*this == _Rhs);
    }
    bool has_value() const
    {
        return !!d;
    }
    bool empty() const
    {
        return !d;
    }
};
```

---

```
int main()
{
    object a = 5, b = 5;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
        << (a == b);
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Your object type seems to me like Boost::any. Whats your goal? Implementing a dynamic type like any or to write the classic OOP super root ?

Comment: The class is quite badly broken. For instance, the Object() initialiser sets 'd->address = NULL', but it never initialises the 'd' pointer in the first place. You need a 

    d = new data();

in the object constructor, and

    delete d;

in the object destructor

There may be more wrong

Comment: @Joseph - If your goal is to make C++ look or work like Java, please don't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing the address members of the 'd' members rather than the values of them. You need to have some way of getting the value of them. Maybe make a virtual method to get the value, which the 'data' derived class can return.

Comment: Or at least he is comparing the member `address` of the `dummy` class pointed to by `d`. But `address` has never been initialized so it might have any value.

Answer (score 1):

this part of your code `type() != typeid(_Rhs.type())`  returns true. so the false part of this ternary operator

`(type() != typeid(_Rhs.type()) ? false : d->address == _Rhs.d->address);` is returned.

I think the problem is here `(typeid(type()) != typeid(_Rhs.type())`

you should check the typeid of this->type() to typeid of _Rhs.type().

**Edit:** I looked at the type method. it returns the type id so I think you should just check
this->type() != _Rhs.type()

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not call the `type` function at all: it returns a reference to a local object and that causes an undefined behaviour so anything can happen. It might help to use `typeid(*this)` in the `operator==` and `operator!=` instead (I'm not quite sure) but there are more broken things in the class.